# How to import JavaScript module that only has JSDoc comments

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have some JavaScript-only modules that I want to import from TypeScript. I know about the `declare module 'whatever';` trick, however, I would like to avoid that because I want to retain typing information. The module that I am trying to import is well-annotated with JSDoc comments, is there any way that I could use these with TypeScript?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best you currently can do is enable the `allowJs` option.  This will make TypeScript use the JSDoc type information and documentation, but it will also try to copy the JavaScript modules to the output, so you'll need to set your other options so that doesn't cause a problem.  See [this issue report](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21435) for the current status.